# How to fetch data from mysql database into ckeditor?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jquery, ckeditor

I have been working on Inline editing, with good results,

but when I saw CKEDitor I'm very impressed!

I want to create the web service for inline editing of website. Without reloading the whole page, just editable content has to be reloaded back into server.

So, I've got a page, like index.html and there is many div, some of these are editable.

I editing some content, it save it successful, but i can't fetch that record from database, because I dont know how to do this.

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to call the data with PHP from your database and return that via JSON and an asynchronous http request (AJAX) and update the DOM with JavaScript.

There's no easy way to say this, but you gonna have to learn how to do it, all I can do is point you in the right direction. Read up on how to use jQuery $.ajax http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ and combine that with some PHP PDO magic http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php.

Comment: Thnks, techouse. I appreciate. But In CKeditor i've added "wiris math editor". It writes Mathematical functions like Integer, derivative, Limits, etc into form of image and saves url of that image into MYSQL database like <img src="">. Here i've no idea how to bring back that data to ckeditor. and after fetching that data it should be editable and after editing it should be successfully saved to database. Please help me. Thank you.